# Concern on the java GC option Xminf

Tags: jvm, websphere

In the regard of java GC option **`-Xminf`**, it specifies the minimum percentage of heap that should be free after a garbage collection. If the free space falls below this amount, the JVM attempts to expand the heap.

However, as for the free percentage, i have a question here. How is that value calculated? Is it from **`100%*freeHeap/AllocatedHeap`** or **`100%*freeHeap/MaximumHeap`**? since it's different, you know, please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its rather freeHeap/AllocatedHeap. And it is not percentage but a decimal number between 0 and 1. Default value is 0.3.